# Terminating process.stdin in node.js

Tags: node.js

The program below simply reads a string and outputs it. When I run this on `cmd`, the program doesn't print out the string. It keeps reading inputs until I terminate with `Ctrl+C`. How do I tell the program when my input string is over, so it can print the output?

```
var concat=require('concat-stream');
var str=[];
process.stdin.pipe(concat(function(buff){
    console.log(buff.toString());
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

`concat-stream` is waiting to receive a `finish` event. In your example that will happen when you close stdin. If you’re running this in a shell you can close stdin by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. If you’re piping something to your process, make sure it closes its stdout when it’s done.

If you’re trying to make your script interactive in the shell, try [split](http://npmjs.org/package/split):

```
process.stdin
  .pipe(require('split')())
  .on('data', function (line) {
    console.log('got “%s”', line);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the answer by Todd Yandell is the right one, and I have already upvoted it, but I wanted to add that besides split, you may also consider the use of [through](https://www.npmjs.org/package/through) which creates a sort of transformer and it would also work in a interactive way, since it is not an aggregation pipe.

Like this example in which everything you write in the standard input gets uppercased in standard output interactively:

```
var through = require('through');

function write(buffer){
    var text = buffer.toString();
    this.queue(text.toUpperCase());
}

function end(){
    this.queue(null);
}

var transform = through(write, end);
process.stdin.pipe(transform).pipe(process.stdout);
```

You may even combine it with split by doing:

```
process.stdin
       .pipe(split())
       .pipe(transform)
       .pipe(process.stdout);
```